# How to say "what the next job"?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

When I have finished my task, and I need next task, which of following variants is correct?

1. What the next job?
2. What next job?
3. What to do next?
4. …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What ***is*** the next task/job/step?
>   What ***shall I*** do next?

You could also just request to give you the plan/project/task list:

> Please share the task list with me.

The sentence "*What the next job?*" lacks the verb.

The sentence "*What next job?*" is grammatically correct, but has a different meaning and might be used as an exclamation in response to a suggestion to go on to the next job.  Your boss, "*You're done with your current job, good!  You can begin your next job, then.*" -- You (surprised), "*What next job?*" (as in "*I thought I was going on vacation!*")

The sentence "*What to do next?*" is the most acceptable from the ones you posted.

Comment: +1 Or, more simply (and more colloquially), *What's next?*

Answer (score 1):

The correct option is to ask:

> What **is** the next task?

Attention please to the using of the auxiliary verb "**is**".